# Combining 2 queries - getting column names in one and using results in another query

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

Building my first Microsoft Access SQL queries. That should not be this hard!
I have 2 tables:

[image: Data table]
[image: AccessRights table]

A user belonging to `GroupA` logged in. I want to show him only those `Data` table rows and columns which `GroupA` is assigned to, like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| Group  |  Data3 | Data4  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| GroupA |   9    |   4    | 
| GroupA |   1    |   5    |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

I tried this silly option:

```
SELECT (select Data from AccessRights where GroupA = "y")
FROM Data
WHERE Data.Group = "GroupA";
```

Comment: Well then, could you please tell us which criteria an answer must meet to be accepted as answer by you? Would it be acceptable for you if you needed to run VBA code to get the problem solved, or are you working just with the query designer?

Comment: I would prefer doing it only in SQL. But it seems impossible without changing the structure of my data. So VBA is good too.

Comment: The root of this problem is the schema.  I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve but this table/column design is not good.  That is why you are having problems with the SQL. What will happen if you assign "y" to all the values in the GroupA and GroupB columns of the AccessRights table?  I think what you are trying to build is a role based authentication system.  Your tables will be different for that.

Comment: @itsben - You're completely right on what I'm trying to build. But I have no idea of how tables should be designed for that. So I just improvised and built on that. If you had any good reference/example on how tables should look like in a role based authentication system, I'd be happy to learn about it. but at least for now I have what I have. I've implemented a SQL-VBA solution to do the task. It's quite similar to [what was offered by shA.t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058822/combining-2-queries-getting-column-names-in-one-and-using-results-in-another-q?noredirect=1#31099570)

Comment: There is a common pitfall with such hand-built authentication systems which new Access users often are not aware of: Users can *easily* get around your protection. E.g., they could press SHIFT when starting Access to get around your startup code and have all database objects available. You can protect yourself against that by Access settings and program code, but any user can still start Access *without* your application (and then have all data available). So, if you need real security, use at least the authentication system Access provides (which regrettably can't protect single columns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this query:

```
SELECT 
    Data.[Group], 
    IIf((SELECT GroupA FROM AccessRights WHERE Data = "Data1")="y",[Data1],Null) AS Data_1, 
    IIf((SELECT GroupA FROM AccessRights WHERE Data = "Data2")="y",[Data2],Null) AS Data_2, 
    IIf((SELECT GroupA FROM AccessRights WHERE Data = "Data3")="y",[Data3],Null) AS Data_3, 
    IIf((SELECT GroupA FROM AccessRights WHERE Data = "Data4")="y",[Data4],Null) AS Data_4
FROM 
    Data
WHERE 
    ((Data.[Group])="GroupA");
```

For this result:

```
Group   | Data_1 | Data_2 | Data_3 | Data_4
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
GroupA  |        |        | 9      | 4
GroupA  |        |        | 1      | 5
```

I just hide values of `Data1` and `Data2`.

---

If you really want to hide your columns you need to use VBA that I create a VBA function that will give your final query string based on your group:

```
Function myQuery(groupName As String) As String
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim i As Integer

    strResult = "SELECT [DATA].[Group]"

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Data], [" & groupName & "] FROM AccessRights WHERE [" & groupName & "] = ""y""")

    For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount
        strResult = strResult & "," & rs.Fields("Data").Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Next i

    strResult = strResult & " FROM [Data] WHERE ((Data.[Group])=""" & groupName & """)"

    myQuery = strResult
End Function
```

For example; `myQuery("GroupA")` will be

```
SELECT [DATA].[Group],Data3,Data4 FROM [Data] WHERE ((Data.[Group])="GroupA")
```

Comment: Why don't you close the recordset and set it to nothing when the function comes to the end? Is it closed/set to nothing automatically?

Comment: @ZygD yes, it is a local variable. and it is a good point to close it before  end.

Comment: So far I like this answer the most, because it does not require me to change my data structure.

Answer (score 4):

It would probably be better just to pivot your data table and add a column named data.  Do the same for access rights.

You data table would look something like this:

```
Group, Data, Value
Groupa,Data1,1
Groupb,Data2,7
...
```

AccessRights like this:

```
Data, Group, Valid
Data1, GroupA, Y
Data2, GroupA, N
```

Then you could just join the two tables together and filter as needed.

```
Select * 
FROM Data D 
  JOIN AccessRights A 
     on D.data = A.data and D.Group = A.Group
WHERE A.Valid = 'Y' 
      and D.Group = 'GroupA'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought about pivoting the tables and I still have this option in my mind. However, I still want to believe there should be some way to get the result without changing anything. I still think that any RDBMS is flexible and I don't want to lose this belief this easily... :)

Comment: This answer shows how RDBMS *is* flexible.  Your way is fighting against the way relational databases work.  Access is somewhat more forgiving in mixing data & presentation but generally to use your table structure you'd select the rows sort out the dynamic columns in the presentation part.  Note that a downside of this approach is all data must have the same type.

Answer (score 1):

@ZygD, Here's the schema:

```
USER
user_id int primary key auto_increment
user_name varchar(100)
password varchar(100)

GROUP
group_id int primary key auto_increment
group_name varchar(100)

DATA
data_id int primary key auto_increment 
data_name varchar(100)

USER_GROUP
user_id int
group_id int


GROUP_DATA
group_id
data_id
```

I'll explain.  First you define your "object types".  You have a USER, GROUP and what you have called DATA. Aside it's probably a good idea to use another word instead of DATA. Use something like ITEM, or even DATAITEM. For this example I will use DATA. Ok, so each one of these tables has an integer value as it's primary key.  The primary key is the unique identifier for the record in the table and it increments automatically.  You can set that up in Access.

Now that you have your three object type tables, you need what are called "join tables" to describe the relationships between the "object type" tables.  The USER_GROUP table says that a user can belong to one or more groups. For example, if User 1 belonged to both Group 1 and Group 2, then you would have two records in the USER_GROUP table to describe those relationships.  The first row would be 1,1 and the second row would be 1,2.

The GROUP_DATA table describes the relationship between GROUP and DATA.  For example, Group 1 could have access to Data 2 and Data 3.  Again, you would have two rows in the GROUP_DATA table to describe those relationships.  The first row would be 1,2 and the second would be 1,3.

Now, because User 1 belongs to Group 1, then User 1 will have access to Data 2 and 3.  Your SQL then becomes simplified:

```
// Authenticate the user with user_name and password:
select @user_id = a.user_id from user a where a.user_name = @user_name and a.password = @password

// Get DATA by user_id
select c.data_id, c.data_name from user a join group b on a.user_id = b.user_id join data c on b.data_id = c.data_id where a.user_id = @user_id
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. Too bad that I don't have much time atm to study it in detail. I really appreciate it and I will get back to it a bit later!

Answer (score 0):

Ok Finally here is the result you required.
The good thing with this solution is that you dont need to run extra script and also just pass the group name as parameter and it will return only the columns you need. Enjoy. :)

```
declare @aa varchar (200) = ''
declare @sql varchar(500) = ''
declare @groupinfo varchar(100) = 'GroupA'

Select @aa = coalesce (case when @aa = '' then Data else @aa + ',' + Data end ,'')
  from [AccessRights] where GroupA = 'y'

Set @sql = 'Select [Group],' +  @aa + ' from Data where [Group] = ' + '''' + @groupinfo + ''''
Exec(@sql)

+--------+--------+--------+
| Group  |  Data3 | Data4  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| GroupA |   9    |   4    | 
| GroupA |   1    |   5    |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: This answer uses T-SQL which will work in Microsoft SQL Server but won't work in Access.

Comment: Nice to know that on SQL Server there would be a solution :)